# Unable to discover directories in a Pentaho repository from Linux command line tool

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I’m unable to get the directories created in a Pentaho repository by using a linux command line tool. As a consequence, I’m unable to run the transformations and/or jobs located in that repository.

These are the tasks I’ve done until now:

1. On a windows machine, I’ve installed a PDI client (*pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342* windows version). From that installation I can launch the Spoon GUI where I can design and run both jobs and transformations perfectly well.
2. Then, on a Linux machine, I’ve set up a Pentaho repository I can connect to from the Spoon GUI and run both jobs and transformations stored in that repository.
3. Moreover, I can successfully invoke these jobs and transformations stored in that repository from a windows command line tool.
4. Then, on the some Linux machine where the pentaho repository lies, I decided to install a PDI client (*pdi-ce-8.2.0.0-342* linux version) to check if I could invoke the jobs and transformations stored on the repository from a linux command line tool.

Once installed the Linux based *pdi-ce* client, and following the instructions [here](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781849696906/1/ch01lvl1sec18/discovering-your-pdi-repository-from-the-command-line-simple) described, I’m attempting to discover the Pentaho repository to be able to invoke the jobs and transformations there stored. The command like the following one is running successfully:

```
$> pan.sh –listrep

#######################################################################
WARNING:  no libwebkitgtk-1.0 detected, some features will be unavailable
Consider installing the package with apt-get or yum.
e.g. 'sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0'
#######################################################################
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; 
support was removed in 8.0
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 45 and column 76
log4j:WARN Element type "rollingPolicy" must be declared.
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 52 and column 14
log4j:WARN The content of element type "appender" must match " 
(errorHandler?,param*,layout?,filter*,appender-ref*)".
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the RollingFileAppender named     
'pdi-execution-appender'
16:02:23,183 INFO  [KarafBoot] Checking to see if         
org.pentaho.clean.karaf.cache is enabled
16:02:23,339 INFO  [KarafInstance]
************************************************************************ 
*** Karaf Instance Number: 2 at /home/usu/telemed/data-integration/./system 
***   /karaf/caches/pan/data-1                                              
*** FastBin Provider Port:52902                                             
*** Karaf Port:8803                                                         
*** OSGI Service Port:9052                                                  
************************************************************************
ago 08, 2019 4:02:24 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback 
lockAquired
[no interest]
2019/08/08 16:02:37 - Pan - Start of run.
2019/08/08 16:02:37 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: 
/home/usu/telemed/.kettle/repositories.xml
#1 : myRepository [PentahoRepository@https://pentaho.uites.isciii.es]
[no interest]
```

That is, the name of the repository (*myRepository*) is being discovered, although I’d like to clarify that to achieve this I had to manually copy the file `%USER_HOME%\.kettle\ repositories.xml` (on the windows machine) to the path `$USER_HOME/.kettle` directory (on the linux machine), that is something that it’s not mentioned in the guide I was following and it’s a step I’m not actually completely sure I should have taken.
The problems arise when I attempt to retrieve the names of the directories created within the repository, that is, at the time of running the following comand I get the following errors:

```
$> kitchen.sh -rep:myRepository –listdir

#######################################################################
WARNING:  no libwebkitgtk-1.0 detected, some features will be unavailable
Consider installing the package with apt-get or yum.
e.g. 'sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0'
#######################################################################
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; 
support was removed in 8.0
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 45 and column 76
log4j:WARN Element type "rollingPolicy" must be declared.
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 52 and column 14
log4j:WARN The content of element type "appender" must match " 
(errorHandler?,param*,layout?,filter*,appender-ref*)".
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the RollingFileAppender named 
'pdi-execution-appender'
16:19:47,362 INFO  [KarafBoot] Checking to see if 
org.pentaho.clean.karaf.cache is enabled
16:19:47,531 INFO  [KarafInstance] 
**************************************************************************
*** Karaf Instance Number: 2 at /home/usu/telemed/data-integration/./system ***
***   /karaf/caches/kitchen/data-1                                            
*** FastBin Provider Port:52902                                             
***
*** Karaf Port:8803                                                                
*** OSGI Service Port:9052                                                  
**************************************************************************
ago 08, 2019 4:19:48 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback 
lockAquired
INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
2019/08/08 16:19:49 - Kitchen - Start of run.
2019/08/08 16:19:49 - RepositoriesMeta - Reading repositories XML file: 
/home/usu/telemed/.kettle/repositories.xml
2019/08/08 16:19:49 - PurRepositoryConnector - Creating security provider
2019/08/08 16:19:49 - PurRepositoryConnector - Creating repository sync 
web service
2019/08/08 16:19:49 - PurRepositoryConnector - Creating repository web 
service
2019/08/08 16:19:49 - PurRepositoryConnector - Creating session sync web 
service
ago 08, 2019 4:19:52 PM 
com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory$Woodstox <init>
WARNING: Expected property not found in Woodstox input factory: {0}
2019/08/08 16:19:52 - PurRepositoryConnector - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, 
build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : Failure access 
to WSDL at: 
https://pentaho.uites.isciii.es/pentaho/webservices/repositorySync?wsdl. 
Ha fallado con: 
2019/08/08 16:19:52 - PurRepositoryConnector -  Connection refused.
2019/08/08 16:19:52 - PurRepositoryConnector - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, 
build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : 
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failure access to WSDL at: 
https://pentaho.uites.isciii.es/pentaho/webservices/repositorySync?wsdl. 
Ha fallado con: 
2019/08/08 16:19:52 - PurRepositoryConnector -  Connection refused.
2019/08/08 16:19:52 - PurRepositoryConnector -  at …
[deleted]
```

To sum up, I don’t know why I cannot get the list of the pentaho directories. I don’t know if the steps I’ve made are consistent or not either. That’s why I’d really appreciate if some Pentaho DI expert could clarify if what I’ve done is right or not, as well as how I should proceed to sort this problem out.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to sort the problem out, thanks to the help received from the Pentaho forums, and I'd like to share it with the rest of the community in case of it can be helpful for anyone.

I had two problems. The first one was that I didn't have `$JAVA_HOME` variable set properly. It has to point to the JDK directory. And the second one is related to the `$USER_HOME/.kettle/repositories.xml` file, which has to include the port where the Pentaho server is listening to (that is, where Tomcat is listening to). So, the `<repository_location_url>` element has to be set as follows:

```
<repository_location_url>http://pentaho_server_url:8080/pentaho</repository_location_url>
```

As said, for anyone who falls in this problem.